# How to update rows in Database with values from data.frame in R conditionally

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, dataframe, rpostgresql

I've a data.frame in R - **matches** with some 1000+ rows

```
names(matches)
[1] "name"  "c_id"  "fname" "lname" "address" "zip_code"    "Weight"

nrow(matches)
[1] 1253
```

I have a postgresql database table - **list_m** with following columns

*db_name, db_cid, db_weight, processing_status, request_id, fname, mname, lname, etc.*

I want to udpate the values of only few columns (db_c_id, db_weight and processing status) in the table using values from the data.frame.

As of now, I am looping over the data.frame to create the update queries and then run the queries.

```
for(row in 1:nrow(matches) {   
    query1 <- paste0(query1, "UPDATE list_m SET db_name = ",matches$name[row],", db_weight = ",matches$weight[row],",  processing_status = 'MATCHED'
 WHERE request_id=111 AND db_c_id = '", matches$c_id[row], "';")
}
```

so it basically creates a query1 variable with

```sql
 UPDATE list_m SET db_name = 'HILLARY', db_weight = 51.41, processing_status = 'MATCHED' WHERE request_id=111 AND db_c_id = '1015310246';

 UPDATE list_m SET db_name = 'SANDERS', db_weight = 45.16, processing_status = 'MATCHED' WHERE request_id=111 AND db_c_id = '1015120982';

 ...

 ...

 ...

 UPDATE list_m SET db_name = 'OBAMA', db_weight = 67.11, processing_status = 'MATCHED' WHERE request_id=111 AND db_c_id = '1015110111'; 

 UPDATE list_m SET db_name = 'TRUMP', db_weight = 41.22, processing_status = 'MATCHED' WHERE request_id=111 AND db_c_id = '1013024634';
```

which will then be executed using

```
dbSendStatement(con, query1)
```

What I would like is to do this by parameterizing the values.. something like

```
query2 <- "UPDATE list_m SET db_name=?,db_weight=?,processing_status='MATCHED' WHERE request_id=111 and db_c_id=?";

dbSendStatement(con, query2, matches$name, matches$weight, matches$c_id)
```

this statement should execute for each row of matches data.frame.

Comment: con is the db connection string:

> drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

> con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname=config$db$name,host=config$db$host,port=config$db$port,user=config$db$user,password=config$db$pass )

Answer (score 3):

This could be closely approximated using `sprintf`

```
sql_string <- "UPDATE list_m SET db_name = %s, db_weight = %s,  processing_status = 'MATCHED' WHERE request_id=111 AND db_c_id = '%s';"

dbSendStatement(con, paste(sprintf(sql_string, matches$name, matches$weight, matches$c_id), collapse=""))
```

Comment: @Parfait changed answer to approximate parameters using `sprintf`

Comment: I thought your approach was great. Just needed to adhere to Postgres syntax and advise OP to export dataframe as temp table, altogether avoiding `for` loop.

Comment: This approach is great! Would it be possible with named parameters instead of just relying on the parameter order?

Comment: @SunWuKung the command could be wrapped in a function which would make it possible to used named parameters.  However, the function will revert back to parameter order if the parameter names are not used when calling the function.