# R - Updating data on SQL Server with RODBC

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, rodbc

I am running a script in R and then need its results to be sent to SQL Server.

During the first run I used this code:

```
sqlSave(conn, df, tablename = "myschema.result_table", rownames=FALSE,
        append=FALSE, varTypes=varTypes)
```

So the table was created and everything worked fine. Now I would like to update the results in a following way:

1. if `Id` exists in `result_table`, update the contents.
2. if `Id` doesn't exist in `result_table`, append the row with this `Id`.

The problem is, if I use:

```
sqlUpdate(conn, df, tablename = "myschema.result_table", index = "Id", fast = FALSE)
```

I get an error as soon as the script finds an `Id` not existing in `result_table`. When using `sqlSave` with `append=TRUE`, everything gets appended without further checks and I get double rows.

Is there any solution to this problem or do I have to create a new result table each time and later merge these tables in SQL?

Comment: Tough one, because unlike MySQL, SQL Server does not directly support an `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause.  One recommendation is to use the `MERGE` statement, but I have no idea how you would do this from the lightweight R API which you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few simple ways to handle this:

1) Bring your existing IDs into R, extract existing IDs from your final dataframe, insert & update based on the two dataframes. Here's an example of how to update a table with a dataframe in R:

[How to update rows in Database with values from data.frame in R conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264942/how-to-update-rows-in-database-with-values-from-data-frame-in-r-conditionally)

2) Dump all results into a table in SQL, then run a stored procedure that updates data for existing IDs, inserts data for non-existing IDs, then clears out said table.

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Col1 = r.Col1
FROM table t 
    JOIN tablefromr r --Existing
        ON t.ID = r.ID

INSERT INTO table
SELECT r.*
FROM tablefromr r
    LEFT JOIN table t
        ON r.ID = t.ID
WHERE t.ID IS NULL --Not Existing

TRUNCATE TABLE tablefromr
```

3) Dump your results into a temp table in SQL (global, so you can access in R) - then do the same steps as #2.

Not sure if this is a one-off, or something you'll be doing constantly. The right answer depends on that. Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks for a detailed description of these ways! I will later investigate which will be most useful when moving on to automate everything.

Comment: any idea which is fastest?